# Uploading an image with Selenium in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

[image: demonstration image]

I'm trying to automate uploading a picture on this website.

I tried locating the element and sending the image path.

```
UploadBtn = b.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[5]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/button[1]/div/div[2]')

path = 'imagepath' 

UploadBtn.send_keys(path)
```

But the problem I'm getting is this:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: 
Message: Element <div class="action-button-text"> is not reachable by keyboard
```

Is there any other way to do it? Or am I doing something incorrectly? Also, please ask me if you want more details about the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just should click the button next

using the `UploadBtn.click()` method

Comment: No, clicking it makes the file upload window pop up, which you can't interact with using Selenium.